# Style every other div using nth-of-type selector with dividing divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to alternate styling of elements using the CSS selector `:nth-of-type` but I'm not getting what I expected. I have a number of `divs` that are either "sections" or "dividers" and I want to style every other section with a different margin and background color.

Using `:nth-of-type(even)` doesn't select any of the sections I'm guessing because there is an element between them and that selector is only counting its index as a child. Seeing as my HTML starts with a section, its numbering would go 1-3-5-7. Changing the selector to `(odd)` makes all the sections turn green.

The image below shows what I'm trying to achieve. Can anyone help me do this without hard-coding a class like "right" and "left"? I'm looking to do this with pure CSS and the HTML I provided.

[image]

```css
.divider{
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.section{
  width: 50%;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.section:nth-of-type(even){
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
```

Comment: `:nth-of-type` does not mean `:nth-of-match`. You probably wanted `:nth-child(even of .section)`, but you will need to wait some years before it's implemented.

Comment: @Oriol `:nth-match` is the correct syntax.

Comment: @Ricky OK, it was dropped from the spec draft anyways.

Comment: @Oriol It has been removed from level 4 selectors?

Comment: @Ricky Yes, it's not in the [Selectors 4 draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/). Probably because people would expect it to count among all the elements matched by the previous part of the selector. The `:nth-child(... of ...)` syntax makes it more clear it only counts among siblings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no point in using `:nth-of-type()` because all your elements are `div`.

Use [**`:nth-child()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) with `4n+3` instead.

Selects every fourth element starting at the third.

```css
.divider{
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.section{
  width: 50%;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.section:nth-child(4n+3){
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
```

---

If you can change your markup, you can use `nth-of-type` targeting `section` elements.

```css
.divider {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.section {
  width: 50%;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.section:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="section"></section>
<div class="divider"></div>
<section class="section"></section>
<div class="divider"></div>
<section class="section"></section>
<div class="divider"></div>
<section class="section"></section>
```

Comment: Oh, so the `nth-of-type` selects the type `div`... I for some reason thought it was selecting the class. That makes sense though! Can you think of any way to do it with any number of divider and section divs?

Comment: You could change your HTML elements for `section` in those that have the class `section`. I will edit for clarity on this. And yeah, `nth-of-type` is not the same as `nth-match`, which is still unsupported.

Comment: Hey, that's a great idea! I like that.

Comment: It looks like your first solution actually works with any number of elements.

Comment: @spencer.sm You're right, I think I pasted a `.divider` where it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just change the divider to horisontal rules? The `div.divider` serves no real purpose otherwise.

```css
.divider{
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.section{
  width: 50%;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.section:nth-of-type(even){
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
hr{
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="section"></div>
<hr class="divider">
<div class="section"></div>
<hr class="divider">
<div class="section"></div>
<hr class="divider">
<div class="section"></div>
```

Comment: The code I gave was a simplified example. The dividing divs in my project will include text so I can't just get rid of them. But changing the tag type is a good idea since it allows me to use the `nth-of-type(even)`

Comment: My apologies - I just read your comments on other answers RE the `.divider` having content ... so yeah - like @Ricky suggested - use sections and divs ... and then `nth-of-type()` will do nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of all the extra divs and use background gradients instead.

```css
.section{
  height: 10vh;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: #00c9e0; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #00c9e0 0%, #00c9e0 50%, #ffffff 50%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #00c9e0 0%,#00c9e0 50%,#ffffff 50%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right,  #00c9e0 0%,#00c9e0 50%,#ffffff 50%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00c9e0', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
.section:nth-of-type(even){
  background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 50%, #ffffff 50%, #00f264 50%, #00f264 50%, #00f264 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 50%,#ffffff 50%,#00f264 50%,#00f264 50%,#00f264 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right,  #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 50%,#ffffff 50%,#00f264 50%,#00f264 50%,#00f264 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00f264',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
```

```html
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
```

Comment: That would be a good solution but I need to have the dividing divs there. What I gave was a simplified example. The dividing divs in my project will include text so I can't just get rid of them.

Comment: @spencer.sm gotcha, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but this works with tables like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #FFF8D6;
        }
    </style>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>Row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td><td>Row 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```